# What effects would be caused by exposure to common life forms with opposite enantiomer biology?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, food, protein-binding, protein-folding

Pretend a human had their body "reflected": heart on the wrong side, etc.; but also at the biochemical level: proteins, sugars, cells, DNA, everything.

What would the effects be of that human's exposure to other Earth life?

I assume that quick death from malnutrition would be inevitable, but would there be more immediate life-threatening consequences?

Would anyone who comes into contact with the mirrored person be at risk?

Would reflected bacteria pose an immediate threat to the ecosystem?

Comment: The title and the text of the question are pretty different. The answer to the title is that all biological proteins are enantiopure.

Comment: I'm going to rephrase it.

Comment: dont mix left/right-hand symmetry with anti-matter substances. those would annihilate "normal" matter

Comment: I'm not referring to antimatter.  Even if it were a "perfect" reflection it wouldn't be antimatter; only the spins of particles would flip.  (At first I thought the weak force would couple with the wrong-orientation elements, but since it would be an emanation of the same field, there would be no change there either.)

Comment: Can the question be reduced to: *Can a hypothetical human life form based on D-amino acids survive in our present world?* This would, to my opinion, be a rigorous question. Note that the question now is too broad. Also note that folks with partly mirrored organs exist. Until edit I vote to close as too 'broad'.

Comment: @AliceD  My question is more specific than your proposal, though.  I don't only mean a human based on D-aminos, I mean a human whose structure *exactly* matches the reverse: amino acids and proteins, but also simple chemicals like glucose (they would taste the sweetness, but it would provide no energy because it cannot be metabolized).  This is relevant for the "would the bacteria that came with them destroy everything or die" scenario.  I'll try to rephrase the question later today, though.

Comment: Please rephrase. It sounds interesting, but as of now it is unclear what you are after. Also, if everything is mirrored, how would you know that glucose will not be metabolized? The issue with hypothetical "what if" questions is that they cannot be answered, only speculated upon. Speculative questions are pretty much always closed. Research on D-amino acids exists afaik and that's why I brought it up as suggestion. Good luck!